# Ionic 3.5.2 or Angular 4 set cookie for an external website before navigate to

Tags: angular, cookies, ionic2, setcookie

I am testing with the Ionic 3.5.2 but I think we get the same with Angular 4.

I am building a front end app using Ionic or Angular (so, my domain now is the localhost).

from my "localhost", I want to navigate to an external website https://xyz.abc.com/a/b/c

The point here is that the external website requires a cookie for its processing like the SSO.

I used the [ng2-cookies](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-cookies) to set the cookie as required
the code looks very simple, something like this

```js
this.cookieService.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10, '/', '.xyz.com');
```

before I navigate to the web site by this code snippet

```js
window.location.href = "https://xyz.abc.com/a/b/c/";
```

Everything looks very simple, but don't know why it doesn't work. It looks like the cookie is rejected.

I think it relates to security or something else. Please help to shed a light if I miss something.
I use this code to check if the cookie is set or not, apparently it is not stored

```js
var t = this.cookieService.check('cookieName');
```

Or I might get a wrong domain name for the cookie?

Comment: Please format as code instead of snipped if the code isn't actually runnable inline.

Comment: Do you solve the issue? I meet the same issue and didn't find the solution。

Answer (score 0):

There are two different domains. One is `abc.com` and one `xyz.com`

```
this.cookieService.set('cookieName', 'cookieValue', 10, '/', '.xyz.com');
```

versus

```
window.location.href = "https://xyz.abc.com/a/b/c/";
```

Besides that, code looks correct.